# Should I use UIWebView or Three20 to write newsreader iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, three20

We're beginning development work on a newsreader app which pulls stories from a RESTful API in XML format. Each story contains:

- Html formatted text with links to external web pages (around 1000 words per story)
- 1 inline advert banner (640x100)
- 1-10 inline images (640x320 each)

The newsreader will load 10 stories at a time when opened. It needs to be robust and performant (smooth scrolling etc).

We're considering whether to display the stories using the native **UIWebView** or **Three20** open source library but am not sure which is the best choice. UIWebView seems to have more flexible text formatting but Three20 sounds more robust and less prone to memory leaks.

I'd appreciate any advice anyone might have from their experiences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the answer is: Oh, it depends. 
The three20 framework offers a lot of things that you would have to do on your own - if you need these offers. If you like URL-based navigation, this might be a plus for going with three20. You mentioned flexible text formatting, which you can achieve with both approaches. three20 allows you to subclass their classes, apply styles, ...

My advice: take a deeper look in the documentation, ask yourself, if you need more than one feature that three20 offers and decide then which way to go. As with all third party frameworks, you'll have to put some effort in making things work.